# how to update uitableview without using timer in swift

Tags: uitableview, swift

I create a downloader app for iphone. And i have tableview for showing active/passive downloads. In custom cell of tableview has progressbar and it is showing %XX download status. Now I am using NSTimer for updating tableview. I set 3 second for NSTIMER and it work nice. However when i try to select some cell and after 3 second it became unselect(because of table reloaded)...

Is there any way to update cell's label(or progressbar) without using NSTimer?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you're using `NSURLSession` or `NSURLConnection` to do your downloads. For `NSURLSession`, mark your table view controller as a `NSURLSessionDataDelegate`, set yourself as the `delegate` of the `URLSession`, and then implement the progress handler:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession,
           downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask,
           didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64,
           totalBytesWritten: Int64,
           totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

    // update your table view here
}
```

Comment: No i cant do that in there. Because i have Download class and all of URLSession methods are in there. However i had created NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(self.error, forKey:"Percentage") on that method you mention. And in custom cell class, I run nstimer in there and read that nsuserdefaults value and update itself. ITs work on 1 download, trying multiple downloads...